# Sharepoint App Only Token Request failing on specific machines only

Tags: sharepoint, token

The Sharepoint site that I am access has been provisioned with App-only ClientId and ClientSecret.

I am using GetAppOnlyAuthenticatedContext with the ClientId and ClientSecret to retrieve List from the Sharepoint Site written in C#.

The strange thing is, the console application works on some machine but failed on my machine. It used to work on my machine.

The validity of the token is valid.

I used PowerShell (Connect-PnpOnline) to verify the request, it failed with "Token Request Failed" on my machine, but it works on another machine.

Is there a cache somewhere that needs to be clear?

I have also generated multiple tokens and none of them works on my machine but they work on other machines.

Please help?

Answer (score 0):

This issue may be related with TLS1.2 support. Please make sure that TLS 1.2 enabled on your machine.

More information is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/troubleshoot/administration/authentication-errors-tls12-support